# Angular 2. Loop of array inside object using ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I have next structure of a component data:

[image]

I want to print a list of `assignedCards` within component's view using `*ngFor`. I do this possible:

```html
<div *ngFor="#item of mission.assignedCards" class="b-progress-bar__item m-progress-bar__item_completed">
<div class="b-progress-bar__inner">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

But it falls with an exception:

[image]

If i test `mission` value, it says me, that `mission` is an object.

[image]

So, i'd like to access `assignedCards` array inside `mission` object and make a loop of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess that the `mission` object is loaded asynchronously. So it's undefined at a first time and is set later...

So you could use the Elvis operator (`mission?.assignedCards`):

```
<div *ngFor="#item of mission?.assignedCards"
      class="b-progress-bar__item m-progress-bar__item_completed">
  <div class="b-progress-bar__inner">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```